# How to get last 20 banned Steam IDs

Tags: steam, anti-cheat, valve

I am working on a cheat analysis system using data from Steam. From [this page](http://www.vacbanned.com/listing/last), we can get the last 20 checked Steam IDs. Is there a way to get the last 20 **banned** Steam IDs?

[VacList](https://vaclist.net/) has a section with the last banned accounts, but I don't know how to extract the data. A solution like that provided by `vacbanned.com` would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information posted on the [Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API), Steam doesn't provide a way to get the last 20 banned Steam IDs.

`GetPlayerBans` takes a comma-delimited list of SteamIDs as input & returns the  Community, VAC, and Economy ban statuses for given players of the SteamIDs.

Based on that, I suspect the listings you mentioned are aggregates of data they've pulled from Steam. For example, they might be listing the last 20 banned accounts out of all the accounts they've checked. Or the 20 bans they've found that where most recently enacted.

You might be able to get the data from one of the other sites you've mentioned, but I didn't see any APIs provided by either VacList or Vacbanned. You could contact them to see if they would be willing to share that information.

Automating the extraction of their content (scraping) and the legality thereof, isn't something I feel qualified to speak about beyond noting that it isn't on topic for game dev.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for your checks! I'll dig some more ;-)